# Xamarin.Forms - Hiding a Frame with a DataTrigger when a bound property is null

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, datatrigger

I have an app that needs to hide a frame when its bound property is empty. There are two frames(inside a CollectionView), each that may or may not receive any data. If they don't, I'd like them to disappear. I've tried it multiple ways including the ways in the attached code.

Here is a screenshot of these frames (The circle controls). The ones that are totally white are not attached to any data, so they are empty or null (honestly not sure which. I believe they are null).

[image]

The following is the code for the first frame.

```
<Frame CornerRadius="50"
       HeightRequest="45"
       WidthRequest="45"
       Padding="0"
       BackgroundColor="{Binding Assessments[0].BackgroundColor}">
           <Frame.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame"
                            Binding="{Binding Assessments[0].TypeLetter}"
                            Value="x:null">
                            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="false"/>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Frame.Triggers>
           <Label Text="{Binding Assessments[0].TypeLetter}"
                  FontSize="24"
                  TextColor="White"
                  FontAttributes="Bold"
                  VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
  </Frame>
```

And this is the code for the second frame.

```
<Frame CornerRadius="50"
       HeightRequest="45"
       WidthRequest="45"
       Padding="0"
       BackgroundColor="{Binding Assessments[1].BackgroundColor}">
    <Frame.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame"
                     Binding="{Binding Assessments[1].TypeLetter, TargetNullValue=''}"
                     Value="">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Frame.Triggers>
    <Label Text="{Binding Assessments[1].TypeLetter}"
           x:Name="lable2"
           FontSize="24"
           TextColor="White"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
</Frame>
```

Neither of these worked. I understand I could solve this issue by implementing a Converter, but I'd love to know if there is a way of doing it this way because I prefer triggers. Way back in 2017 it seemed there were some bugs around using the x:null method, but i'd assume after 4 years it would be fixed.

Anyway, any help/pointers would be awesome. I'm at a loss as to how to make this work.

Also, here is the code for the object they get bound to.

```
public class Assessment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AssessmentType Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return IsComplete ? "#558f45" : "Gray"; }
        set { BackgroundColor = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string Date => Start.ToString("MMM dd") + " - " + End.ToString("MMM dd");
    public string TypeLetter => Type.ToString().Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();

    public Assessment(string name, AssessmentType type, bool isComplete, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        IsComplete = isComplete;
        Start = startTime;
        End = endTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use Xaml binding like `Assessments[1].TypeLetter`

Comment: @FreakyAli Those Bindings are actually currently working. That's how I'm getting the O and the P for the label on the frame.

Comment: Is it? They didn't work that way in the past so I thought they still don't. Thanks for the response

Comment: instead of Type.ToString(), try using Convert.ToString(Type) may be u will get what u require.

Answer (score 2):

Use Converter

```
public class NullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
           return false;
        //else if()
        //{ write your logic if any}
        else 
           return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:YourProject.NameSpace.xxx.Converters"
...
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <converters:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Frame CornerRadius="50"
       HeightRequest="45"
       WidthRequest="45"
       Padding="0"
       IsVisible="{Binding Assessments[1].TypeLetter,Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"
       BackgroundColor="{Binding Assessments[1].BackgroundColor}">
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do this using Triggers? A converter will work just fine, but if there is a way to do this with a DataTrigger, that would be prefered.